# Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. ImageButton

Tags: eval, imagebutton, databinder, servertag

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval("ProdImagePath","/Images/{0}") %>" />
```

> I have retrieved the ProdImagePath from the database and Images is the internal folder which has Images and I am trying to retrieve the image from that folder